Можно ли поставить свой ретранслятор wifi на сеть, где я не являюсь админом?
Учусь в университете. Недавно переселили в новую общагу, где стоят в коридорах роутеры/ретрансляторы huawei (контролирует их "отдел интернета" от самого университета). Подключение к сети идет с помощью своего логина и пароля (WPA2-802.1X - AES) от университетского аккаунта. Сигнал в комнату доходит очень плохо - частые переключения на другие роутеры/ретрансляторы, плохой сигнал, плохая скорость.
Сам вопрос: можно ли купить какой-нибудь роутер/ретранслятор wifi, поставить его у двери в комнату, подключиться им по своему логину и паролю к ближайшей точке wifi (удаленно, без кабеля) и раздавать уже в комнате от этой новой точки (типа режим модема на телефоне)?
Может, можете посоветовать более хорошее решение? Сразу скажу, что подключения через ethernet своих роутеров нет и не будет, провести свой интернет нельзя, купить симку с интернетом и модем - не вариант, т.к. мобильная сеть тут ловит тоже ужасно (обычно E или H+).
